# Compare string to a large sentence and get percentage of Similarity

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, similarity, levenshtein-distance

I am trying out a self project in which even if someone inputs a misspelled word, the program compares it with a sentence and then outputs a particular percentage based on percentage of text similarity.

While Searching for Techniques online ,I came across many algorithms (Levenshein Distance,Hamming Distance ,Jaccard Similarity etc).Also python modules such as Difflib and Fuzzywuzzy ,but did not get an expected output

**Using Fuzzywuzzy** :

```
process.extract("radisson",ds,scorer=fuzz.partial_ratio,limit=10)
```

The above snippet spits out predicted output ,However if i change one letter from the query as follows :

```
 process.extract("radison",ds,scorer=fuzz.partial_ratio,limit=10)
```

The output is totally different.Where no word related to 'radison' is found.

**Expected Behaviour**:

**Input**:
string = "radison" 
text1  = "Hotel radisson palace" 
text2  = "radison homes" 
text3  = "Hotel radis"

**Output**: 
Percentage of Similarity is as follows: 
with text1 90% 
with text2 100% 
with text3 65%

Comment: Are you looking for the highest score of your target word over each of the words in the sentence?

Comment: yes in terms of text similarity.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a way to compare two words for similarity (this is where you'd use levenshtein, hamming, etc) and a way to turn a sentence into a sequence of words (`str.split()` is the most basic implementation, or you could use something like [`ntlk.tokenize`](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html)), the trivial implementation is:

```
def similarity(w1:str, w2:str) -> float:
    pass

def tokenize(sentence:str) -> [str]:
    pass

def word_in_sentence(word:str, sentence:str) -> float:
    return max(similarity(word, token) for token in tokenize(sentence))
```